# Paw Paw 'Brandy' with slight blue cast

Tags: spirits

I'm working on recipe development for a Paw Paw 'brandy' and have had a slight blue cast to the product.  Can anyone weigh in on the outcome?  Thank you

Comment: This is going to be my next experiment.

Comment: Can you elaborate any further on the other ingredients? I'm intrigued by this since I used to live in an area where PawPaw grew natively... The fruit is yellow and the skins are green... Did you use bark from the tree? I'd want to rule out other possibilities before looking at the fruit for the blue cast...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert distiller, but I can offer some general advice that may help with your Paw Paw 'brandy' recipe. The blue cast in your product could be due to a few reasons:

1. The presence of impurities: The fermentation and distillation process might not have been thorough, leading to the presence of impurities in your brandy. To fix this issue, you can try refining your distillation process or using a better filtration method.
2. Copper reaction: If you're using copper equipment during distillation, it's possible that the copper is reacting with compounds in the Paw Paw fruit, leading to a blue tint. To minimize this, make sure your equipment is clean and well-maintained. Additionally, you can try using stainless steel equipment to see if the issue persists.
3. Fruit quality: The quality and ripeness of the Paw Paw fruit used in your recipe could affect the final color. Make sure to use ripe, high-quality fruit, and consider experimenting with different varieties of Paw Paw to see if the blue cast is specific to a certain type.
4. Oxidation: If the blue cast appears after bottling or storing the brandy, it could be due to oxidation. To minimize oxidation, make sure to store the brandy in a cool, dark place and use bottles with airtight seals.
5. Natural colorants: Some fruits, including Paw Paw, contain pigments such as anthocyanins that can cause color changes in the final product. You can try adding fining agents like activated carbon to help remove these color compounds, but be cautious as this may also strip some of the flavors from your brandy.

Please consult with a professional or do further research before making any significant changes to your process.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable advice regarding my Paw Paw 'brandy' recipe. Your insights are greatly appreciated. I'll take your suggestions into consideration and make adjustments to my process accordingly. I'll ensure a more thorough fermentation and distillation process to reduce impurities, and I'll also explore using stainless steel equipment to minimize any potential copper reactions. Selecting ripe and high-quality Paw Paw fruit is a priority, and I'll experiment with different varieties to determine if the blue cast is fruit-specific. Your tips on minimizing oxidation and understanding t